# Is it possible to convert matlab p-code to something viewable?

Tags: decompilation

A simple disp("Hello World") gave me this :

```
7630 312e 3030 7630 302e 3030 0007 301c
d3e7 7fb1 0000 0004 0000 002a 0000 0035
4c97 ee76 779b d4b9 3948 d7ea 798c 05ba
c67a 2a56 c4de d7f9 7446 1d59 0472 b700
cfc0 84f6 6c3d a042 08a7
```

### pcode

> Create content-obscured, executable files (pcoded files).
>      pcode F1 F2... makes content-obscured versions of F1, F2...
>
> The arguments F1, F2... must describe MATLAB functions or files 
>      containing MATLAB code.
>
> If the flag -INPLACE is used, the result is placed in the same
>      directory in which the corresponding file was found.
>      Otherwise, the result is placed in the current directory.  Any
>      existing results will be overwritten.  Needed private and class 
>      directories will be created in the current directory if they do
>      not already exist.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like [.p files are AES encrypted](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/165381), with an unknown key, and have been since 2008 from the date of these posts.

However, as matlab itself can read those files, it needs to include the decryption algorithm and key, from where it can be reverse engineered. And it seems like [someone has done this](https://sites.google.com/site/sippeyfunlabs/matlab-hacks/please-do-not-secure-your-password-in-matlab-p-code) and produced an online .p code decryptor. They won't share the code, but you can use the [online decryptor](http://web-service.sippey.org/de_pcode.html).

So, to answer your question: Yes, there is an online decriptor for it.

Comment: links are offline

Answer (score 0):

It seems that someone created decompiler and publish some deobfuscated matlab pcode.

https://github.com/firstborg/matlab-2017a.git

The author promise to publish deobfuscation technology for donation in BTC.

Comment: It is usually encouraged to post answers that are more then merely a link to some tool or site. May I interest you in adding some information about the tool?

Comment: link is offline